# Tree structure sql select

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Here is my table structure:

[image: User Table]

**here:**

- John is Org Head
- jonah is Project manager
- Dennis and David Team Manager
- Ram and Grace work under Dennis
- Arjun and Nico work under David

[image: Organization Chart]

**Problem:** Jonah can only see people below him  similarly david can only see people below him. how do I frame my sql. Known solution do I need to while loop using php till i reach the Trees End or is there any better solutions.

**Note:** number of people in various stages may increase.

Comment: This is something of a FAQ

Comment: can you guide me to some links I tried searching the forum before posting this maybe i was using the wrong keywords

Comment: Well, this is a hierarchical model and you're using MySQL. See where that gets you.

Answer (score 0):

You might need to alter your schema, but one of the ways to handle trees in SQL are Nested Sets.

The are at least few lib on github that implement this in eloquent.

https://github.com/lazychaser/laravel4-nestedset
https://github.com/etrepat/baum

Or just look yourself: https://www.google.pl/webhp?ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=laravel%20nested%20set